# (React js) Audio src is updating on setState but the audio playing doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I am trying to build a mini 2-track audio player with React. The audio is centrally controlled by a html audio element with a track-list inside a child component. The (yet to be styled) player can be seen [here](http://theseboys.com/).

I can tell in the React dev tools that clicking the individual track select buttons does update the src of the audio element (thanks to the help of a member on here), however, the playing audio doesn't change. I've posted the Application code below.

Is it even possible to change the playing audio by updating the state in this way? Help would be hugely appreciated.

```
var TRACKLIST = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "song a",
        source: "./audio/test.m4a"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "song b",
        source: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/wwy.mp3"
    }
]

function Track(props) {
    return (
        <div className="track">
            <div className="meta">
                <div className="name">
                    <h2>{props.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <audio>
                    <source src={props.source} />
                </audio>
            </div>
            <button className="select" onClick={function() {props.onChange(props.source);}} >
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

var Application = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isPlaying: "./audio/test.m4a"
        };
    },

    onTrackChange: function(source) {
        this.setState({ isPlaying: source })
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="player">
                <div className="tracklist">
                    {this.props.tracklist.map(function(track){
                        return <Track
                                    key={track.id}
                                    name={track.name}
                                    source={track.source}
                                    onChange={this.onTrackChange} />
                    }.bind(this))}
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <audio controls>
                        <source src={this.state.isPlaying} />
                    </audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

// Render the UI
ReactDOM.render(
    <Application tracklist={TRACKLIST} />,
    document.getElementById('Player')
);
```

Comment: Can you try `onChange={this.onTrackChange.bind(this)}`?

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately but thanks though.

Comment: In your example, there is this error: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery". Did you notice this?

Comment: I've noticed that but I've no idea why the error is given because I am including JQuery. Same on another website I have but it seems insignificant as JQuery still performs as normal.

Comment: I don't think it is the root cause of your issue. It is just a dependency of bootstrap. If you include jquery it should remove the error message. Nice to remove some noise. Furthermore, what convinces you that `setState` works?

Comment: I use the React Developer Tools plugin and there I can see that the state changes on click. Link to plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Audio files cannot be changed by just changing the `src` like an image as there is caching. You will need to `load` it and `play` it again.

```
onTrackChange: function(source) {
       this.setState({ isPlaying: source },function(){
            this.refs.audio.pause();
            this.refs.audio.load();
            this.refs.audio.play();
       })
}
```

The callback handles the pausing, loading and playing after the state has been changed. Remember to add a `ref` to the audio tag.

```
<audio controls ref="audio">
   <source src={this.state.isPlaying} />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 11):

**Using Hooks**

import *useRef* and create a instance of it.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
const audioRef = useRef()
```

Function to update song.

```
const updateSong = (source) => {
    setSource(source);
    if(audioRef.current){
        audioRef.current.pause();
        audioRef.current.load();
        audioRef.current.play();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add *ref* to audio tag.

```
<audio controls ref={audioRef}>
    <source src={source} type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>
```

Comment: No reference to how the function is called from the audio player.

Comment: you can call that function anywhere(on button click etc.) for me I created music card component that display a song and on click play it. you just need to pass the src(source) of the song when calling the function.

Comment: Thanks @Anurag Sharma this appears to be the better answer with React 16+

Answer (score 3):

**Using KEY**

The best way to solve this problem is just add a '**key**' attribute:

```
<audio key={props.id} controls>
    <source src={props.source}/ type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting different key-attributes on the audio-tag depending on the source works if you are okay with loosing the playing state and time.