# How to reload audio component on source change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-audio, react-props, use-effect

I have an audio player that sits at the bottom of a page.  On the page, there is a list of podcast episodes, each with a 'play episode' button underneath.  Each podcast is an instance of the EpisodeInfo component to which I pass podcast information as props.

The audio player:

```
import React, {useState, useRef , useEffect} from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/audioPlayer.module.scss'
import {BsArrowCounterclockwise, BsArrowClockwise,} from 'react-icons/bs'
import {FaPlay, FaPause} from 'react-icons/fa'

const AudioPlayer = (props) => {
    // State
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
    const [episodeUrl, setEpisodeUrl] = useState(props.url);

    // References
    const audioPlayer = useRef(null);   // reference our audio component
    const progressBar = useRef(null);   // reference our progress bar
    const animationRef = useRef(null);  // reference the animation
    const isInitialMount = useRef(true);  //reference the initial mount

    useEffect(() => {
        const seconds = Math.floor(audioPlayer.current.duration);
        setDuration(seconds);
        progressBar.current.max = seconds;
    }, [audioPlayer?.current?.loadedmetadata, audioPlayer?.current?.readyState]);

    const calculateTime = (secs) => {
        const minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
        const returnedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`;
        const seconds = Math.floor(secs % 60);
        const returnedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
        return `${returnedMinutes}:${returnedSeconds}`;
    }

    const togglePlayPause = () => {
        const prevValue = isPlaying;
        setIsPlaying(!prevValue);
        if (!prevValue && episodeUrl) {
          audioPlayer.current.play();
          animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying)
        } else {
          audioPlayer.current.pause();
          cancelAnimationFrame(animationRef.current);
        }
    }

    const whilePlaying = () => {
        progressBar.current.value = audioPlayer.current.currentTime;
        changePlayerCurrentTime();
        animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    }

    const changeRange = () => {
        audioPlayer.current.currentTime = progressBar.current.value;
        changePlayerCurrentTime();
    }

    const changePlayerCurrentTime = () => {
        progressBar.current.style.setProperty('--seek-before-width', `${progressBar.current.value / duration * 100}%`)
        setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
    }

    const backTen = () => {
        progressBar.current.value = Number(progressBar.current.value - 10);
        changeRange();
    }

    const forwardTen = () => {
        progressBar.current.value = Number(parseFloat(progressBar.current.value) + 10);
        changeRange();
      }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isInitialMount.current) {
            isInitialMount.current = false;
         } else {
            setEpisodeUrl(props.url);
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        }
    }, [props.url])

    return (
        <div className={styles.audioPlayer}>
            <audio ref={audioPlayer} src={episodeUrl} preload="metadata" ></audio>
            <button className={styles.button} onClick={backTen}><BsArrowCounterclockwise /></button>
            <button className={styles.button} onClick={togglePlayPause}> {isPlaying ? <FaPause /> : <FaPlay />} </button>
            <button className={styles.button} onClick={forwardTen}><BsArrowClockwise /></button>

            <div className={styles.time}>{calculateTime(currentTime)}</div>
            <input type="range" className={styles.progressBar} defaultValue="0" ref={progressBar} onChange={changeRange} />
            <div className={styles.time}>{(duration && !isNaN(duration)) && calculateTime(duration)}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export {AudioPlayer};
```

The page on which the audio player sits:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../components/navbar'
import styles from '../styles/listen.module.scss'
import EpisodeInfo from '../components/episodeInfo'
import { AudioPlayer } from '../components/AudioPlayer'
import { db } from '../config/firebaseConfig'
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore'


export default function Listen () {
    
    // Firestore
    const episodesRef = db.collection("episodes");
    const query = episodesRef.orderBy('episodeNumber');
    const [episodesReturned] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'id'});

    //State
    const [episodeUrl, setEpisodeUrl] = useState('/episode1.mp3');

    function handleCallback (childData) {
        setEpisodeUrl("/episode" + childData + ".mp3");
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.body}>
            <Navbar />
            <div className={styles.mainWrapper}>
                {episodesReturned && episodesReturned.slice(0).reverse().map(episode => <EpisodeInfo key={episode.id} episode={episode} parentCallback={handleCallback} />)}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.sticky}>
                <AudioPlayer url={episodeUrl} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the component that is rendered for each episode on the listen to page:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/episodeInfo.module.scss'

export default function EpisodeInfo (props) {

    const { episodeNumber, episodeTitle, blurb, length, date} = props.episode

    function passNameToParent () {
        props.parentCallback(episodeNumber)
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <img src="album-cover.jpg" className={styles.albumMain}/>
            <div className={styles.info}>
                <p className={styles.number}>EP. {episodeNumber}</p>
                <h1 className={styles.title}>{episodeTitle}</h1>
                <p className={styles.blurb}>{blurb}</p>
                <div>
                    <a onClick={passNameToParent} className={styles.button}>Play Episode</a>
                    <h3 className={styles.meta}>{length} mins</h3>
                    <h3 className={styles.meta}>•</h3>
                    <h3 className={styles.meta}>{date}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When a 'play episode' button is clicked, it passes its episode number up to the listen to the page, which then changes the source input to the audio player that is passed as a prop (at least that's what I think it's doing.)

This works fine and well, the source changes when I press a button under an episode, however, the only way to get the new source to play is to manually pause and then play the audio player.  I've tried to resolve this by using `useEffect` to pause, load, and play the player when the URL prop changes, but it doesn't work.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something, perhaps there is a much simpler way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(React js) Audio src is updating on setState but the audio playing doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64981388/1870780)

Comment: I looked at that previously and thought I was using it correctly but perhaps not.  I'll have another go at it.