# How do you update the state of the audio tag in Remix?

Tags: state, html5-audio, src, remix

In react you have to useRef to get the audio src to change
([As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577182/react-js-audio-src-is-updating-on-setstate-but-the-audio-playing-doesnt-chang)

Does anyone have any experience doing this in remix, the solutions in that thread didn't seem to work.

I tried the useRef method and setting the key prop

Comment: Found a way. in the documentation search shouldRevalidate or just add this

```
export function shouldRevalidate({
  currentParams,
  nextParams,
  defaultShouldRevalidate,
}) {
  if (currentParams !== nextParams) {
    return true;
  }

  return defaultShouldRevalidate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. in the documentation search shouldRevalidate or just add this

```
export function shouldRevalidate({
  currentParams,
  nextParams,
  defaultShouldRevalidate,
}) {
  if (currentParams !== nextParams) {
    return true;
  }

  return defaultShouldRevalidate;
}
```